# Dynamically sized select element IE not scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

When I dynamically add `option` elements to a `select` element with a size of say 10 on IE, a scrollbar does not appear once my list of options exceeds the height of my select element, and I am unable to scroll to the rest of the options. This only happens on IE and is an issue when dynamically adding/removing options. Anyone know of workarounds? I've tried creating wrappers and one approach that might work is re-rendering the entire `select` element each time, but that is wasteful

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution to this specific problem, 
but you get to ignore a lot of the hassle with cross-browser support on UI elements by using jQuery UI.
If it's possible, you should take a look at https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/
It's more easily customizable, so if the default select-box' off-by-one pixels annoy you, you can get around that too by using it :)